# Spark dataframe to hive jdbc issue

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, jdbc, hive

I have a small spark program just to test Dataframe writing on Hive.

First I read a simple csv described as follows:

```
coluna1;coluna2;coluna3
aaa;bbb;ccc;
ddd;eee;fff;
```

and try to create table / record with this implementation:

```
df_u.write.mode("overwrite").option("spark.sql.dialect", "hiveql").
  jdbc(args(4), "tabela_teste",properties).
```

The problems is that at this time the program gives me an exception like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:35 cannot recognize input near 'TEXT' ',' 'coluna2' in column type
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:241)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:227)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:244)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeUpdate(HiveStatement.java:389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:302)
    at org.app.SparkTest$.main(SparkTest.scala:69)
    at org.app.SparkTest.main(SparkTest.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:35 cannot recognize input near 'TEXT' ',' 'coluna2' in column type
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:388)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:145)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runInternal(SQLOperation.java:215)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.run(Operation.java:326)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:425)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementAsync(HiveSessionImpl.java:402)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatementAsync(CLIService.java:258)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:500)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1313)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1298)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingProcessor.process(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:746)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException:line 1:35 cannot recognize input near 'TEXT' ',' 'coluna2' in column type
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:204)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:418)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:312)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1188)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:143)
```

It seems that is something related to the SQL-dialect of hive, isn't it?

I'm using a hadoop 2.6 cluster, hive 1.1 and spark 1.6.1.

Comment: SparkSQL can write directly into Hive tables, at HDFS level. That's the way you have to follow. Because as you can see, Hive does not support all JDBC data types; and even if the types were compatible, Hive does not support INSERT via JDBC *(unless you create a "transactional" Hive table which is a nasty hack IMHO)*.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter , i create a *.jar that tries to save a data-frame in hive by using spark-sql :
sqlContext.sql("create table digital_ofc.nbsTv as select * from nbs_tv")
i do not know why, but the jar does not work when i apply to spark-submit.
it says:
exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.1] failure: ``with'' expected but identifier create found:

create table digital_ofc.nbsTv as select * from nbs_tv | 


but when i write the code in spark-shell, it strangely works :(

Comment: Is your DataFrame linked explicitely to a HiveContext? Because the spark-shell does some things at initialization that may not be done by default in spark-submit.

Comment: Did you try to execute tow distinct `CREATE` and `INSERT SELECT` commands, instead of `CREATE AS SELECT`?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, even if i execute it distinct, the error persists:


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.1] failure: ``with'' expected but identifier create found

create table digital_ofc.teste